# Can you get a Char 0x05 into an XDocument that will then throw on XDocument.ToString?

Tags: .net, linq-to-xml, invalid-characters

I have an `XDocument` that is throwing an invalid character (0x05) exception on `ToString`.

To help locate where I could be allowing a 0x05 char in where in the XDocument API can you let in a 0x05 character without some exception at that point, only to be thrown at `ToString`?

Specifically, as far as I recall, I only use the new Linq XML API, except that I do use some XmlSerialization through an extension method to return it to an `XElement`.

<sub>Just to show this was a worthy question before I found the simple answer: `XElement:Parse` *does* throw when the 0x05 character is included.</sub>

Comment: You are linking to a question that you are going to delete once this question is answered. And to understand what you are doing I have to follow another link in the linked question. If you instead edited this question into a simpler self-contained question without links you would probably have a higher chance of getting a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that simply setting the `.Value` of an `XElement` does not check for invalid charaters :-(

```
element.Value = "test" & Chr(5) & "5"
```

The above doesn't throw, until you then call `XDocument.ToString` on the containing Xml.